# Infinite Loop Newton Raphson

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, newtons-method

Very new matlab user here. The code you see below works great for solving EQUATION 2 but when I switch to EQUATION 1 matlab becomes "busy" and nothing seems to work.

ctrl+c, ctrl+d, ctrl+ dont seem to work but I would like to solve the underlying problem anyway

```
function [x1, relErr] = NewtonRaphson(x0, TOL, MAX)

    x = sym('x');    
    f(x) = x*exp(-x); %EQUATION 1
    %f(x) = x^2-6 %EQUATION 2
    df = diff(f);
    relErr = 1:MAX;

    for i = 1:MAX,

       x1 = double(x0 - f(x0) / df(x0));

       % Compute relative approximated error
       relErr(i) = abs(x1-x0)/abs(x1);

       if( abs(x0-x1) < TOL )
           char(x1);
           fprintf('Newton: Solution %0.5f in %d iterations\n',x1,i);
           relErr = relErr(1:i);
           plot(relErr);
           lambda = abs(x1-6)/((abs(x0-6))^2);
           char(lambda);
           fprintf('Newton: Lamda = %0.5f\n',lambda);
           return;
       end
       x0 = x1   ;
    end

    display('Method failed, hit max iterations');

end
```

Comment: Where's your definition of `MAX`? See http://sscce.org/

Comment: And the initial value of `x0`?

Comment: x0 works at all values for Equation 2, and never works for Equation 1.

MAX is the maximum number of iterations. I have been using 1e5.

Comment: Does it work if you make `TOL` very big? Perhaps you're asking for too much precision than what you can get from `MAX` number of iterations?

Comment: It seems to work with the following values >> NewtonRaphson(1,0.01,100)
Method failed, hit max iterations

ans =

   101

Comment: Try it with `(-1, 0.01, 100)` and tell me what happens.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic kind of problem for teaching numerical analysis. Have a look at [the plot of this function `x*exp(-x)` (via FooPlot)](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJ4KmV4cCgtMSp4KSIsImNvbG9yIjoiIzAwMDAwMCJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MTAwMH1d).

You can see there is a zero to find at `x=0` (and this is obvious by inspection). But the function also decays out towards positive infinity.

Thus, the Newton-Raphson algorithm can get stuck trying to walk its way out to the zero that lives far out at infinity. This problem is [mentioned in the Wikipedia article on this method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Bad_starting_points).

You can try different initial conditions (in this case, things to the left of `x=0` should work). You can also try an approach called successive over-relaxation, which basically means you choose a fraction between 0 and 1, call it `w` and you set `x0 = w*x1 + (1-w)*x0` at the end of your loop, shading yourself to stay a little close to the point you're already at instead of fully jumping to the calculated `x1`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get an infinite loop is that Newton-Raphson for the function

```
f(x) = x * exp(-x)
```

doesn't converge for initial guesses greater than 1.

To see why not, look at the following chart, where the blue curve is x * exp(-x), the dotted line is at x = 1 and the red lines show successive Newton-Raphson iterations, starting at x = 3.

[image]

You can see that each iteration moves further away from the root at x = 0 and towards the "fake root" at x = +infinity as described in EMS's answer.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the answer of EMS:

For `f(x)=x*exp(-x)` one gets `f'(x)=(1-x)*exp(-x)`, so that the Newton iteration reads as

```
x[n+1]=N(x[n])=x[n]-x[n]/(1-x[n])=-x[n]**2/(1-x[n])
```

but also equally as

```
x[n+1]=N(x[n])=x[n]+x[n]/(x[n]-1)=x[n]+1+1/(x[n]-1)
```

From the first form you see the quadratic convergence towards `x=0` for small values of `x`, say `|x|<0.5`.

But from the second form you see that for `x[n]>1` the next value will be bigger, and the increment will always be larger than `1`, so you do not even get some kind of pseudo-convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
relErr(i) = abs(x1-x0)/abs(x0);
```

so you compare relative to previous value as opposed to current value. The other pitfall with NR method is near when `df=0` the steps become too large. I suggest you bound the solution and do not allow the steps to go outside the bounds.